# Retain jdbc batch statements after exception

Tags: java, postgresql

I am inserting data from java in to postgresql database. I am using jdbc postgresql driver to make connection. I am creating a batch of statements and sending to insert in one go. But if connection is lost then java tries to connect with database again using connection pooling. I tried to execute the batch again but no record is inserted.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_RECORD_TABLE_SQL);

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

pstmt.setLong(1, toLong(fields[0]));

pstmt.setLong(2, toLong(fields[1]));

....

pstmt.addBatch();

}

try{

pstmt.executeBatch();

} catch (Exception e) {

  Thread.sleep(60000);

  pstmt.executeBatch();

}
```

My question is that Can I retain the batch of statements that can be executed if exception occurs?

Thanks,

Saurabh Gupta

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad thing to catch the general Exception.

It is a bad thing to sleep for a minute, or any other "human" time value.

It is a bad thing to re-execute the same code in the catch block just like if nothing had occurred, but you're handling an exception there! And you should catch the new possible exception in the catch block.

Better to:

```
try
{

   int[] updateCounts = pstmt.executeBatch();

} 
catch (BatchUpdateException be) 
{
    // if one of the commands sent to the database fails to execute properly 
    // or attempts to return a result set
    handleException(be);
    return;
}
catch (SQLException se) 
{
    //if a database access error occurs, this method is called on a closed Statement 
    //or the driver does not support batch statements
    handleException(se);
    return;
}
```

Do you need a transaction? That is, if an error occurs should you rollback to the state the db was before you started, or is it ok to retry?

Comment: I am using BatchUpdateException but I mentioned it wrong in question. I put thread on sleep so that it will reconnect with database again. If I will not execute the batch again then I will lost the data. Please correct me If I am wrong, preparedStatement.executeBatch() will update whole batch as one transaction rather than two or more statements. So I want to retry to insert same batch again.

Comment: it depends by the java version you are using. _"The possible implementations and return values have been modified in the Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, version 1.3 to accommodate the option of continuing to proccess commands in a batch update after a BatchUpdateException object has been thrown."_